# Error in ConcatRelated

Tags: string-concatenation

Here is my table structure:

```
ID1  - autonumber
TDate - Date/Time
TTime - Date/Time
TID - Text
TMessage - Text
Tcode - text
```

TMessage value can be 100+ characters. There can be more than 1 TMessage for each TID

Sample input:

```
TDate      TID     TTime          TMessage
1/9/2014   93378   12:28:28 PM  aaaaaaaaaaaa
7/24/2014  02645   12:56:22 PM  bbbbbbbbbbbb 
7/24/2014  02645   12:56:30 PM  cccccccccccc
```

Output should be:

```
TDate,    TID,    TMessage
1/9/2014   93378   aaaaaaaaaa              
7/24/2014  02645   bbbbbbbbbb,cccccccccccc  (the output can be more than 255 chars.)
```

This is my query/module (got from Stackoverflow and Allen Brown)

Query (SQL View)

```
SELECT sub.TDate, sub.TID, ConcatRelated("[TMessage]","RawData2","[TDate] = '" & sub.TDate & "' AND [TID] = '" & sub.TID & "'","[TDate], [TID]") AS concat_Message
FROM (SELECT q.TDate, q.TID FROM RawData2 AS q GROUP BY q.TDate, q.TID)  AS sub
ORDER BY sub.TDate, sub.TID;
```

Function :

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function ConcatRelated(strField As String, _
    strTable As String, _
    Optional strWhere1 As Date, _
    Optional strWhere2 As String, _
    Optional strOrderBy1 As Date, _
    Optional strOrderBy2 As String, _
    Optional strSeparator = ", ") As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Generate a concatenated string of related records.
    'Return:    String variant, or Null if no matches.
    'Arguments: strField = name of field to get results from and concatenate.
    '           strTable = name of a table or query.
    '           strWhere = WHERE clause to choose the right values.
    '           strOrderBy = ORDER BY clause, for sorting the values.
    '           strSeparator = characters to use between the concatenated values.
    'Notes:     1. Use square brackets around field/table names with spaces or odd characters.
    '           2. strField can be a Multi-valued field (A2007 and later), but strOrderBy cannot.
    '           3. Nulls are omitted, zero-length strings (ZLSs) are returned as ZLSs.
    '           4. Returning more than 255 characters to a recordset triggers this Access bug:
    '               http://allenbrowne.com/bug-16.html
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset         'Related records
    Dim rsMV As DAO.Recordset       'Multi-valued field recordset
    Dim strSql As String            'SQL statement
    Dim strOut As String            'Output string to concatenate to.
    Dim lngLen As Long              'Length of string.
    Dim bIsMultiValue As Boolean    'Flag if strField is a multi-valued field.

    'Initialize to Null
    ConcatRelated = Null

    'Build SQL string, and get the records.
    strSql = "SELECT " & strField & " FROM " & strTable
    If strWhere1 <> vbNullString And strWhere2 <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " WHERE " & strWhere1 And strWhere2
    End If
    If strOrderBy1 <> vbNullString And strOrderBy2 <> vbNullString Then
        strSql = strSql & " ORDER BY " & strOrderBy1 And strOrderBy2
    End If
    Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenDynaset)
    'Determine if the requested field is multi-valued (Type is above 100.)
    bIsMultiValue = (rs(0).Type > 100)

    'Loop through the matching records
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If bIsMultiValue Then
            'For multi-valued field, loop through the values
            Set rsMV = rs(0).Value
            Do While Not rsMV.EOF
                If Not IsNull(rsMV(0)) Then
                    strOut = strOut & rsMV(0) & strSeparator
                End If
                rsMV.MoveNext
            Loop
            Set rsMV = Nothing
        ElseIf Not IsNull(rs(0)) Then
            strOut = strOut & rs(0) & strSeparator
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close

    'Return the string without the trailing separator.
    lngLen = Len(strOut) - Len(strSeparator)
    If lngLen > 0 Then
        ConcatRelated = Left(strOut, lngLen)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    'Clean up
    Set rsMV = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "ConcatRelated()"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

Currently, this is the output:

```
TDate     TID   Concat_Message
1/9/2014  93378   #Error
7/24/2014 02645   #Error
7/24/2014 04533   #Error
```

Question 1 - What could be the reason for the Error? How to solve it?

Question 2 - Can I just create a table manually with Memo field so I can store the result of the Query to this table?

Comment: This looks like VB.net with Access SQL, but the formatting is so bad, I am not even certain enough to edit the tags.  Can you clean up the question?

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language that you're using. You can do so by clicking the [edit] link under your question. Thank you.